# Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister

Tags: hibernate, session, jpa, exception, wildfly

Can anyone help me with this exception? I tried solving this but couldn't. It happening after I put this:

```
 public Entidade() {
      FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
      fazenda = (Fazenda) session.getAttribute("fazenda");
 }
```

**Then this exception appeared:**

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister
>       at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       ... 13 more
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : br.com.teclogica.model.Especie
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:60) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:85) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:87) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:163) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.UnionSubclassEntityPersister.(UnionSubclassEntityPersister.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_112]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_112]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_112]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [rt.jar:1.8.0_112]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>       ... 17 more

**This is the class that the exception told me it could not instantiate:**

```
@Entity
public class Especie extends Entidade implements Serializable, BaseInterface {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3726838446858443624L;

    private String familia;
    private String descricao;

    public String getDescricao() {
         return descricao;
     }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
         this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getFamilia() {
         return familia;
    }

    public void setFamilia(String familia) {
         this.familia = familia;
    }
}
```

**And this is the parent class where I changed that block of code:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Entidade implements Serializable, BaseInterface {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8347493862254802654L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "seq")
    protected long id;
    private boolean excluivel;
    protected String nome;
    @OneToOne
    private Fazenda fazenda;

    public Entidade() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        fazenda = (Fazenda) session.getAttribute("fazenda");
    }

    public long getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isExcluivel() {
         return excluivel;
    }

    public void setExcluivel(boolean excluivel) {
         this.excluivel = excluivel;
    }

    public String getNome() {
         return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
         this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
         return nome;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         final int prime = 31;
         int result = 1;
         result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
         return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
             return true;
        if (obj == null)
             return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Entidade other = (Entidade) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Fazenda getFazenda() {
         return fazenda;
    }

    public void setFazenda(Fazenda fazenda) {
         this.fazenda = fazenda;
    }

}
```

Comment: but that exception did not appear as thrown from that code, because there is no persistence at all in that code